# Automatically add dash into text typed into a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, textinput

I have a regular expression in which the first five characters are only letters, then a dash, and then five numbers.

I would like the dash to automatically appear after the user enters the first five characters into the text field.

```
func applyRegex(text: String) -> Bool {
    var regex = ""
    let regexForLetters = "([a-zA-Z]{1,5})"
    let regexForDigits = "[a-zA-Z]{5}-[0-9]{0,5}"
        
    if text.count <= 5 {
        regex = regexForLetters
    } else if text.count > 5 {
        regex = regexForDigits
    }
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex).evaluate(with: text)
}
    
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return false }
    let newString = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    return applyRegex(text: newString)
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your current code? What's happening?

Comment: I enter a dash from the keyboard, but dash should appear automatically(without keyboard) after five characters.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that this line:

```
return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex).evaluate(with: text)
```

is returning True or False. It's not **changing** `newString`.

So, if the user types "ABCDE" and then types "F" your code says:

`return False` ... *"don't change the text in the textField"*

If the user types "ABCDE" and then types "1" your code says:

`return True` ... *"change the text in the textField to "ABCDE1"*

Instead of writing a func that tells you if `newString` passes the regex test, you want to write a func that ***formats `newString`***.

Here is *one* example:

```
func format(str: String) -> String {
    
    // split the string into two parts
    //  prior to the "-" and
    //  after the "-"
    let parts: [String] = str.components(separatedBy: "-")

    var letterStr = ""
    var numStr = ""

    // loop through the first part
    //  ignore any non-Letter chars
    //  append Letter chars to letterStr
    //  stop if we get to 5 Letters
    var idx = parts[0].startIndex
    for _ in 0..<parts[0].count {
        if parts[0][idx].isLetter {
            letterStr.append(parts[0][idx])
        }
        idx = parts[0].index(after: idx)
        if letterStr.count == 5 {
            break
        }
    }

    // if we got 5 Letters, append the "-"
    if letterStr.count == 5 {
        letterStr += "-"
    }
    
    // if we have two parts (i.e. the string already had a "-")
    //  AND we got 5 Letters (plus the "-")
    // loop through the second part
    //  ignore any non-Number chars
    //  append Number chars to numStr
    //  stop if we get to 5 Numbers
    if parts.count == 2, letterStr.count == 6 {
        var idx = parts[1].startIndex
        for _ in 0..<parts[1].count {
            if parts[1][idx].isNumber {
                numStr.append(parts[1][idx])
            }
            idx = parts[1].index(after: idx)
            if numStr.count == 5 {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    // return the modified string
    return letterStr + numStr
    
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return false }
    let newString = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    // format the new string
    let s = format(str: newString)
    // update the text in the text field
    textField.text = s
    // return false, because we just updated the text
    return false
}
```

Note that this is very hard-coded, so it will only work for this specific task.

Also, it can get very quirky when the user moves the insertion point / caret back into the string and types a new letter/number... but I don't know how you would want to handle that.

Without knowing anything else about exactly what you're trying to do, I'd maybe suggest using **two** text fields -- one for the Letters and one for the Numbers.

Lots of approaches are much more flexible (such as defining a *mask* like "AAAAA-NNNNN"). If that example doesn't work for you, take a look at some of the results by searching for `UITextField format input`.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [InputMask_](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-ios) library for a ready solution, with all the edge cases taken into consideration.